# How to insert the array 's element to the other one in turns?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to insert an array into another array. For example, there are two strings, String_1 is `123456789` and String_2 is `abcdefghijk`. What I want to do is to insert `string_2[i]` behind the `string_1[i]` from 0 to i. So the expected result is `1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9ijk`. I made a following function to achieve it but it failed.

```
void conj(char *string1, char *string2)
{
   int length = 0, i = 0, j =0;
   char *string[] = {string1, string2};
   char *string_temp = string[0];
   int length_1 = strlen(string[0]);
   int length_2 = strlen(string[1]);

   /* To compare  the length of string[0] with the other one */  
    if (length_1 >= length_2)
       length = length_1;
    else
       length = length_2;

   /* The error maybe occurs in the following code*/
   for (j=0; j<length; j++)
    {
      if (j < length_1)
         {
           *(string_temp+i) = *(string[0]+j);
            i++;
         }
      if (j < length_2 )
         {
           string_temp[i] = string[1][j];
           i++;
         }
    }

  printf("After asserting, the string is %s", string_temp);
}
```

After compiling, the result of string is in a mess.For example, string1 :12345678; string2 :abcdefgijk; the final result is:laabacbecfbgdhijk.

I also found that a single element could be changed, for instance, `(string_temp+2) = *(string[0]+2);`. But after I added another one, like `(string_temp+4) = *(string[0]+4);`, the string didn't change.
Any help and guidance to help me solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry,it should be insert>

Comment: one mistake i can see immediately is the `*(string[0] + j)`. Could you possibly mean `*(&string[0] + j)`?

Comment: The easy way is to put your result in a 3rd string instead of inserting characters into the 1st.  Inserting into the middle of a string involves moving all the elements from the insertion to the end, and will change the indices of the other elements.  Alternatively, calculate the final length and positions of the last characters taken from each string, and build the result from the end so you don't overwrite the original characters until you don't need them anymore (provided there's enough unused space in the array to fit the result).

Comment: I used it as a char ** which is equal to string[0][j].

Comment: Post text as text, not images!

Comment: @Dmitri,the second solution, which built the result from the end of string,can't make each element insert behind the other one in turns.Or there  is something wrong with my understanding about your answers.

Comment: @Ghoster If you build the new string backward, you start with the higher indices and work backward to the lower ones, and you're always writing to a higher index than you read from -- so you only overwrite the parts of the original string that you've already copied.  Remember that the new string will be longer than the original, so the first elements you write to are past the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake. You are changing `string[0]` which is `string1` and using it to create new string.

Here

Change this

```
char *string_temp = string[0];
```

to

```
char *string_temp = malloc(100);
```

beacuse in this line

`*(string_temp+i) = *(string[0]+j);`  you are changing string[0] also cause `string_temp` points to same address as that of `string1`

Comment: Another question, which way can  take place of the malloc?